# Displaying xml data on a html table

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I am trying to display data from a xml file on to a html file with a xsl and JavaScript files. I'm using Apache NetBeans. I was also hoping to include images for each of my book elements that will also be brought in to the table. If anyone has any other ideas, please help

My files are books.xml, booksStyle.xsl, index.html and script.js. I also have a schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="booksStyle.xsl"?>

<catalog>
    <book id="1">
        <name>I Know You Did It</name>
        <genre>Thriller</genre>
        <description>On her first day at a new school, Ruby finds a note in her locker saying I Know You Did It. She's terrified that someone has found out she was responsible for the death of a girl called Hannah in a playground when they were both toddlers – a secret she has been keeping guiltily for ten years.</description>
        <code>156-05</code>
        <quantity>56</quantity>
        <price>7.99</price>
    </book>
    <book id="2">
        <name>Robin Williams, when the Laughter Stops</name>
        <genre>Biography</genre>
        <description>When the Laughter Stops," examines this brutal and tragic dichotomy, casting its incisive eye on the comedians' personal lives, while separating fact from fiction, creative work from the human being behind it, to probe not just from where their genius sprung - but how that same wellspring often lead to their demise.</description>
        <code>145-04</code>
        <quantity>13</quantity>
        <price>12.59</price>
    </book>
    <book id="3">
        <name>Invisible Girl</name>
        <genre>Psychological Fiction</genre>
        <description>Saffyre Maddox has been suffering the aftermath of a traumatizing incident for over 8 years. She is self-harming and her guardian-uncle sends her to therapy.</description>
        <code>056-06</code>
        <quantity>120</quantity>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
    <book id="4">
        <name>The Golden Ass</name>
        <genre>Picaresque Novel</genre>
        <description>The Metamorphoses of Apuleius, which Augustine of Hippo referred to as The Golden Ass, is the only ancient Roman novel in Latin to survive in its entirety. The protagonist of the novel is Lucius. At the end of the novel, he is revealed to be from Madaurus, the hometown of Apuleius himself.</description>
        <code>020-08</code>
        <quantity>42</quantity>
        <price>18.19</price>
    </book>
    <book  id="5">
        <name>Four Seasons in Japan</name>
        <genre>Coming-of-age</genre>
        <description>It is a story about Ayako, a fierce and strict old woman who runs a coffee shop in the small town of Onomichi, where she has just taken guardianship of her grandson, Kyo. Haunted by long-buried family tragedy, both have suffered extreme loss and feel unable to open up to each other.</description>
        <code>304-03</code>
        <quantity>34</quantity>
        <price>16.38</price>
    </book>
    <book id="6">
        <name>Can You Keep a Secret?</name>
        <genre>Crime Fiction</genre>
        <description>Lindsey hasn't spoken to Rachel in twenty years, not since her brother's 18th birthday party at their parents' remote country house. A night that shattered so many friendships – and left Rachel's father dead. Now Thornbury Hall is up for sale, and the old gang are back there, together again.</description>
        <code>150-02</code>
        <quantity>61</quantity>
        <price>10.36</price>
    </book>
    <book id="7">
        <name>To Sleep In a Sea of Stars</name>
        <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
        <description>During a routine survey mission on an uncolonized planet, Kira finds an alien relic. At first she's delighted, but elation turns to terror when the ancient dust around her begins to move. As war erupts among the stars, Kira is launched into a galaxy-spanning odyssey of discovery and transformation.</description>
        <code>145.02</code>
        <quantity>30</quantity>
        <price>14.55</price>
    </book>
    <book id="8">
        <name>Tokyo Ever After</name>
        <genre>Fiction</genre>
        <description>Tokyo Ever After follows Izumi, a normal Asian girl who has found a home in her small group of Asian girlfriends in a town that is almost entirely white. While trying to find out more information about her father, one of Izumi's friends finds him, but he is not what they expect.</description>
        <code>054-02</code>
        <quantity>24</quantity>
        <price>11.19</price>
    </book>
    <book id="9">
        <name>Forgotten Women: The Scientists</name>
        <genre>Biography</genre>
        <description>The Scientists celebrates 48* unsung heroines whose hugely important, yet broadly unacknowledged or incorrectly attributed, discoveries have transformed our understanding of the scientific world. *The number of Nobel-prize-winning women.</description>
        <code>065-04</code>
        <quantity>67</quantity>
        <price>13.60</price>
    </book>
    <book id="10">
        <name>Yellowface</name>
        <genre>Psychological Fiction</genre>
        <description>June Hayward and her friend Athena Liu, a Chinese-American author who has been working on a book about Chinese laborers in World War I. Following Athena's untimely death, June steals her manuscript and attempts to build up her career through Athena's work.</description>
        <code>157-06</code>
        <quantity>34</quantity>
        <price>13.99</price>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Style</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="catalog/book">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script scr="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id = "book_data">
            <tr><th>Name</th><th>Genre</th><th>Description</th><th>Code</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "books.xml",
               dataType: "xml",
               complete: function(xml){
                    console.log(xml);

                    $(xml).find('catalog/book').each(function(){
                        var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                        var genre = $(this).find('genre').text();
                        var description = $(this).find('description').text();
                        $('<tr></tr>').html('<th>' +name+ '</th><td>$' +genre+ '</td><td>$' +description+ '</td>').appendTo('#book_data');
                });
            },
        });
    });
```

I've tried using ajax in my JavaScript, to display, there's no errors coming up but the data isn't being shown. I also tried using XSLT to do the display, and I'm getting error for the xml version and encoding declare.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below, it works ok for me. Check the attached image. I suggest you add your own css and image sequence as required. Thanks

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Book Catalog</title>
    <!-- Link to the external CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", false);
        xhttp.send("");
        return xhttp.responseXML;
      }
      function loadXSLDoc() {
  var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "booksStyle.xsl", false); // Make sure the XSLT file is named "booksStyle.xsl"
  xhttp.send("");
  return xhttp.responseXML;
}

      function displayCatalog() {
  var xml = loadXMLDoc();
  var xsl = loadXSLDoc();

  if (xml && xsl) {
    try {
      var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
      xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
      var resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);

      if (resultDocument) {
        document.getElementById("catalog").appendChild(resultDocument);
      } else {
        console.error("Result document is not valid.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during XSLT transformation:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.error("XML or XSLT document not loaded.");
  }
}

      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="displayCatalog()">
    <div id="catalog"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: That code doesn't seem to be working on Netbeans or on notepad++. What application were you using to run it?

Comment: You need to run it under a server, I recommend you use [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/), Wampp, or Laragon.

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL is just missing HTML elements, but it works.

For a pure JavaScript variant - modern browsers have an asynchronous `fetch()` function. For XML you can wrap it into your own async function:

```
async function fetchXML(url) {
    // asynchronous functions can wait for other async calls
    // so fetch the url, read the response as text and parse into a DOM
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(
      await(
        await fetch(url)
      ).text(),
      'application/xml'
    );
}
```

CSS selectors can be used to address elements in the HTML document and
XML documents. The following example defines a template row in
the HTML document and clones it for each book.

```js
// call the load function and catch errors
loadBooks('./books.xml').catch((e) => console.log(e));

// define an asynchronous load function 
async function loadBooks(url) {
  // fetch the template structure from the document
  const template = document.querySelector('[data-template-for=book]');
  delete template.dataset.templateFor;
  // store some context
  const container = template.parentNode;
  const nextElement = template.nextElementSibling;
  // remove template from document
  template.remove();

  const books = await fetchXML(url);

  // iterate the book elements (use CSS selectors to fetch them)
  books.querySelectorAll('catalog > book').forEach(
    (book) => {
      const row = template.cloneNode(true);
      // iterate the template cells
      row.querySelectorAll('[data-field]').forEach(
        (cell) => {
          // and fill them
          cell.textContent = book.querySelector(cell.dataset.field)?.textContent || '';
        }
      );
      container.insertBefore(row, nextElement);
    }
  );
}

// simulate the XML fetch
async function fetchXML(url) {
   const data = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="1">
        <name>I Know You Did It</name>
        <genre>Thriller</genre>
        <description>On her first day at a new school, Ruby finds a note in her locker saying I Know You Did It. She's terrified that someone has found out she was responsible for the death of a girl called Hannah in a playground when they were both toddlers – a secret she has been keeping guiltily for ten years.</description>
        <code>156-05</code>
        <quantity>56</quantity>
        <price>7.99</price>
    </book>
    <book id="2">
        <name>Robin Williams, when the Laughter Stops</name>
        <genre>Biography</genre>
        <description>When the Laughter Stops," examines this brutal and tragic dichotomy, casting its incisive eye on the comedians' personal lives, while separating fact from fiction, creative work from the human being behind it, to probe not just from where their genius sprung - but how that same wellspring often lead to their demise.</description>
        <code>145-04</code>
        <quantity>13</quantity>
        <price>12.59</price>
    </book>
    <book id="3">
        <name>Invisible Girl</name>
        <genre>Psychological Fiction</genre>
        <description>Saffyre Maddox has been suffering the aftermath of a traumatizing incident for over 8 years. She is self-harming and her guardian-uncle sends her to therapy.</description>
        <code>056-06</code>
        <quantity>120</quantity>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
  </catalog>`;
  return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Books</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
  </tr>
  <tr data-template-for="book">
    <td data-field="name"></td>
    <td data-field="genre"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```